# How do I convert a Sympy expression to a floating point number?

Tags: python, floating-point, sympy, units-of-measurement

I have been trying to swap from using Pint.py for units to using the Sympy units system.
I have examples of both code working in the image.
I need help please, converting the Sympy expresion to a floating point number. I have tried evalf() and simplify() but neither change the expression at all.

The first image is using Sympy units, the second is Pint units, which is giving the correct output.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `x.evalf()`?

Comment: Yes, evalf() does not change the display at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy will not evaluate a function having an argument with a unit. So for evaluation do `x.subs(u.deg, pi/180).subs(u.rad, 1).evalf() -> 2.8*Wb` in whatever units are being used for theta. This feels clunky. Trig functions should probably do this automatically upon a request to evaluate. This has been raised [as an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12443).